# Spring Undertow Scaling - "to many open files" during load testing in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, undertow, horizontal-scaling

I developed a microservice using Spring Boot and Undertow. I was performance testing the service by "load testing in 200 threads".

Some requests fail with a 502 error:  "to many open files"

My ulimit:

```
[root@server-886d5f4f8-54494 java]# ulimit -n
1048576
```

If, for example, I load testing 150 threads, the application runs without error and delivers 15,000 throughput per second.

pod setting: requests 2 CPU, no limits

undertow settings:

```
server:
  undertow:
    threads:
      worker: 128
      io: 16
```

Should 1 instance be accepting more concurrent requests? For example 1000 or 10000?

I need to provide about 5000 concurrent connections / requests. Should I scale horizontally in this case (5000/20 = 25 replicas) or is 1 instance able to handle more and have I configured it incorrectly?

**UPDATE**

lsof | wc -l output during load test: 9791 (this count is much less than ulimit in containter 1048576)

**UPDATE 2**
Application launched in Kubernetes

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes 
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       2059511              2059511              signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

**UPDATE 3**

All requests go through the NodePort

Comment: check `cat /proc/<pid>/limits `

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from backend?

Comment: @Svetlin Zarev Added info -  Max open files            1048576              1048576              files